# Does loading same bootstrap css file multiple times in angular 6 slow downs performance

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am using angular 6 in my application inside src/index.html i found bootstrap is loading as

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
```

and each component.ts of my application also using bootstrap in their respective files as

```
 styleUrls:[
    **'../../../../assets/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',**
    '../../../../assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css']
```

I thought in a single page there are multple components like (header, footer, sidebar, body).
It means bootstrap css has been loaded four times for each component in one page load.

**Que 1. Does loading multiple times the same css file cause slow page load ?**

In order to reduce page load can i remove all the bootstrap css from each component and import bootstrap css in main style.css as

```
@import 'assets/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Slow page load problem occurs while development of application when i change even a single character, at the time page refresh and takes longer than usual page loading time.

Suggest how to proceed with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can load the Bootstrap into the main CSS file, and delete the styleUrls. Those styleUrls are primarily for modular control over specific component styling. In Angular you must add CSS files in the .json file, under the 'styles' section which by default has the global 'styles.css' listed.